# How should I prepare for Plantera?

Tags: terraria

I am so stuck trying to get gear for Plantera  And it takes so long for ectoplasm. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best preparation for Plantera is a good battlefield.  I usually hollow out a large area in the middle of the underground jungle, and put a row of platforms across it about every 10 blocks up.  Make the area about 50 by 60 (large enough you can move around freely, but small enough you can have the whole thing on your screen at once), and put down a campfire in the middle of it.  Leave a hole in the platforms on the sides so you can drop down quickly.  Then when you fight plantera you can use your grappling hook to move quickly up and to the sides and stay out of its way.  Be careful, and try to take as few hits as possible, and Hallowed armor should be enough.

For the weapon, use a repeater or a nice gun like the megashark with LOTS of good ammo to take it down.  And of course make all the potions you can.  Ironskin, well-fed, and swiftness at the very least.

For equipment, prioritize mobility, but keep your Obsidian shield handy so you don't get knocked around by tentacles.  I also suggest one of those red rings made by combining a philosopher's stone and a band of regeneration for the reduced potion sickness time.

There are simpler ways to get it done.  If you have a lot of gold you can set up teleporters at either end of a long hallway, then lure plantera to it.  Teleport, then shoot plantera while it follows you to the other end of the hallway, and repeat.  Laying down asphalt on the top and bottom of your boss fight area can also make it easier.  (make asphalt with gel and stone at a blend-o-matic, bought from the steampunker)

Comment: Doesn't Plantera go into pissy boss mode immediately after reaching the surface these days?

Comment: I think Plantera gets angry if you exit the Jungle biome, reach the surface, or take it below a certain amount of health.

Comment: Ah, that's probably been patched, then.  I'll edit my answer.  I'll mention the teleporter idea from Marco instead.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the easiest way (by far) is to make a single hallway of about 200 blocks long. Put [a teleporter](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Teleporter) on each sides with a lever connected to it. Now grab a minishark (or any ranged weapon but the minishark is probably the fastest way at your level) and a lot of ammo. Now simply make Plantera spawn and run/fly to your hallway. Go to the far side first and wait for plantera to arrive. Once he's getting close to you simply teleport to the other side and fire down your hallway. In his second form Plantera does move faster so a longer hallway might be easier but 200 blocks worked for me. You should have no problems with plantera like this.

Comment: If you want i can make a video about this when i get home tonight.